# Почему QML выдает ошибку неизвестный тип при возвращении из метода: Unknown method return type

Tags: qt, qml

Регистрирую тип как положенно:

```
qmlRegisterType<ApplicationInfo>("com", 1, 0, "ApplicationInfo");
```

Тем не менее при попытке из qml вызвать метод возвращающий этот тип получаю ошибку, (хотя объект этого типа создается без проблем: проблемы именно с возвращением):

```
Error: Unknown method return type: ApplicationInfo
```

Как правильно зарегистрировать его?

Comment: `qmlRegisterType` вызывается до загрузки qml файла?

Comment: да, причем пробовала просто в qml объект этого типа объявить ("ApplicationInfo;")- не ругается. А возвращать этот тип не хочет.

Comment: Добавьте код `main.cpp` и заголовок `qml-файла` к вопросу

Comment: регистрирую я не в мэйне, а методе класса (но не класса  ApplicationInfo) и импорт в заголовке qml есть.

Comment: Приложите минимальный проект с проблемой, чтобы его можно было у себя запускать -- так гадать можно сколько угодно

Comment: А тот метод класса вызывался? И из метода класса прекрасно регистрируется тип

Comment: Вызывается конечно. Меня удивляет что объект класса ApplicationInfo я могу завести в qml , никаких вопросов у компилятора не возникает а вызвать метод этот тип возвращающий не могу.

Comment: >  Приложите минимальный проект с проблемой, чтобы его можно было у себя запускать -- так гадать можно сколько угодно

Comment: `ApplicationInfo` не состоит в `namespace`, случаем?

Comment: @ixSci нет, ошибка нашлась в следующем: возвращаемый объект был константный, и qml это не нравилось. Убрала константность - заработало. Ответ оформлю чуть позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в следующем:

из метода возвращался разыменованный константный указатель

```
const ApplicationInfo * m_pActiveApplication;
return ApplicationInfo* m_pActiveApplication ;
```

Что qml категорически не мог понять, решилось заменой возвращаемого значения на

```
return const_cast<ApplicationInfo*>(m_pActiveApplication);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так регистрировать:

```
qmlRegisterType<ApplicationInfo>("com.ApplicationInfo", 1, 0, "ApplicationInfo");
```

И так импортировать:

```
import com.ApplicationInfo 1.0
```

Пример из `main.cpp`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        qmlRegisterType<ApplicationInfo>("com.ApplicationInfo", 1, 0, "ApplicationInfo");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // И так находит тип
    Foo();

    // И так:
    qmlRegisterType<ApplicationInfo>("com.ApplicationInfo", 1, 0, "ApplicationInfo");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: У меня там через точку после com есть имя, просто я вырезала (это имя компании) Завтра добавлю минимальный компилируемый пример